# Command not acting properly in script

Tags: bash

The command:

```
value=${value%?}
```

will remove the last character from a variable.
Is there any logical reason why it would not work from within a script?
In my script it has no effect whatsoever.

```
if [[ $line =~ "What I want" ]]
    then
            if [[ $CURRENT -eq 3 ]]
            then
                    echo  "line is " $line 
                    value=`echo "$line" | awk '{print $4}'`
                    echo "value = "$value   
                    value=${value%?}
                    echo "value = $value "

                    break
            fi
fi
```

I cant post the whole script, but this is the piece I refer to. The loop is being entered properly, but the 2 echo $value lines return the same thing.

Edit - this question still stands. The code works fine line bu line in a terminal, but all together in a script it fails.

Comment: Are you sure your script calling bash and not, say, sh?

Comment: it has #!/bin/bash at the start, if thats what youo are referring to. I'm new to bash..

Comment: `echo` the new value immediately after the change. It should be there. The problem is somewhere else - aren't you perphaps changing the value in a subshell?

Comment: @choroba, That seems like the most likely answer, but for the life of me I cant figure it out. I was under the impression though, that doing something within an if statement did NOT create a subshell?

Comment: @confusified: Show the code. The right side of a pipe runs in a subshell.

Comment: Added script snippet to question.

Comment: `echo "<$value>"` might show you some unexpected characters. Or even `echo "$value" | xxd`.

Comment: echo "<$value>"  What is this supposed to show exactly?

Answer (score 2):

Echo adds an extra line character to $value in this line:

```
value=`echo "$line" | awk '{print $4}'`
```

And afaik that extra char is removed with `%?`, so it seems it does not change anything at all.

Try `echo -n` instead, which does not add `\n` to the string:

```
value=`echo -n "$line" | awk '{print $4}'`
```

Comment: Nope, Still happening. The value before and after the %? is the same

Comment: Even better use `printf`, which is far more portable than echo with -e or -n option.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have provided only the relevant part in the code and not the whole file, I'm going to assume that the first line of your file reads **`#!/bin/sh'**. This is your problem. What you are trying to do (parameter  expansion) is specific to bash, so unless **/bin/sh** points to bash via a symlink, then you are running the script in a shell which does not understand bash parameter expansion.

To see what /bin/sh really is you can do: **ls -l /bin/sh**. And to remedy the situation, force the script to run in bash by changing the `shebang' at the top to read **`#!/bin/bash'**